# Why does child element "row" not match height of parent element "container"?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Just a quick on in relation to the following site:

[christmas.drcrittall.com](http://www.christmas.drcrittall.com)

My question, is why despite the following CSS:

```
html, body {

    height:100%;

}

/* Background image for website */ 
body {

    /*background: url("images/crumpled.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;*/
    background: url("../img/crumpled.jpg") no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% 100%;
    /*margin-bottom:5%;*/                                   

}

#header {

    height:20%;
    border-style: solid; 
    border-color:red;
    /*padding:0px;  */                      

}

#middle {

    height:60%;
    /* border-style: solid; 
    border-color:green;*/

}

#cap {

    height:20%;

    border-style: solid; 
    border-color:blue;
    /* Previously the click here text was overflowing out of this div. See here to see how to deal with this: https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/o/overflow/ */
    /*overflow:auto;*/.

}

#form {

    min-height:20%; /* Setting min-height of white-space beneath body enables container to expand with the form as it gets bigger */ 
    display:none;  /* This div is initially hidden until click button which activates jquery animation */


}

#main_image {


    max-width:100%;
    max-height:60vh; /*Set max and min heights to 60vh to lock within this container ie stop images expanding out */
    min-height:60vh;

}

#candle_image {

    width:100%;
    height:100%; 

}

#top_paper {

    width:100%;
    max-height:100%; 


}

/* Make row height and columns fill entire height of containers */

.row, .col-md-6, .col-md-4, .col-md-6, .col-md-12, .col-md-8, .col-md-2, .col-md-3, {

    height:100%; 

}
```

Does the row within #cap and #head not fill 100% of the height? I have used flex box to center the font within the header, but can not seem to do the same with the cap... Here is the HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class = "container-fluid center_font" id = "header">
        <div class = "row" style = "border-style: solid; border-color:black;">
            <div class = "col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                <font id = "dear"> Merry Christmas! </font>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class = "container-fluid center_font" id = "middle">
        <div class = "row"><!-- style = "border-style:solid; border-color:black;">-->
            <div class = "col-md-3" id = "holly_1" style = "padding-top:10%;">
                <img src = "../img/candles.png" id = "candle_image" class = "img-fluid">    
            </div>
            <div class = "col-md-6 col-xs-12 center_font"><!-- style = "border-style:solid; border-color:yellow;">-->
                <img src = "" id = "main_image" class = "img-circle">
            </div> 
            <div class = "col-md-3" id = "holly_2" style = "padding-top:10%;">
                <img src = "../img/candles.png" id = "candle_image" class = "img-fluid">    
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
    <div class = "container-fluid" id = "cap"><!-- style = "border-style:solid; border-color:green;">-->
        <div class = "row" style = "border-style: solid; border-color:black;">
            <div class = "col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 center_font">                  
                <font class = "ammend" id = "dear" style = "font-size:45px;"> Love from Matthew</font><br>  
                <!--<a href = "#" id = "reveal">
                    <font id = "dear" class = "fiddle" style = "font-size: 20px;">Click Me</font>
                </a> 
                -->
            </div> 
            <div class = "col-md-offset-3 col-md-6 col-xs-12 center_font">
                <a href = "#" id = "reveal">
                    <font id = "dear" class = "fiddle" style = "font-size: 20px;">Click Me</font>
                </a> 
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div> 
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Font size is too big and collapses the offset columns, and you are missing `center_font` class on `#cap`.

- Add `center_font` class to `#cap`.
- Change `font-size` from `45px` to less or equal than `36px` on `font#dear.ammend` to keep 1 line of text ("Love from Matthew").

[image: Check image]

Comment: Thanks that does make things look much better! I did have a couple of questions however. Firstly, why 36 for the font? and secondly, why does the row height not match the container height despite that class being set to 100%?

Comment: If you leave 45px as font-size and add center_font, you'll see it will cover all container's height, 36px would be the limit on my end to preserve just one line, but adjust as you wish, it may vary depending on your resolution. Considering you used 1 line on the header I assumed you would want 1 line as well, it also leaves a bit more breathe for text, otherwise it would be very tight to pictures. :)